# gedit backround error, I can see through the window where it is supposed to be white

Tags: 17.04, gedit

There is suddenly an annoying visual error when I use Gedit for Ubuntu 17.04.

Normally when I open Gedit, it shows me the text of a file, or nothing, and when I write on my keyboard there are some letters. But when I open it now, the screen (for example my desktop backround) of what was there before, is still there in the backround of the text inside gedit. And this gedit window acts now like a picture window.

It's hard to explain but this is what it looks like:

[image: screenshot showing the problem]

If I delete and reinstall gedit, nothing changes.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Delete this file and it will fix your problem:

In `terminal`...

```
rm -i ~/.xinputrc
```

It will recreate itself when needed.